# Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expiring in 1 day(s)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am making an android application in which i am authenticating my user from firebase auth and only reading data from firestore(till now).

recently i got an email from firestore about security rules and my data is open and so on...
it goes like:-

*You chose to start developing in **Test Mode**, which leaves your Cloud Firestore database **completely open** to the Internet. Because your app is vulnerable to attackers, your Firestore security rules were configured to stop allowing requests after the first 30 days.
In 1 day(s), all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied. Before that time, please write **strong security rules** that allow your app to function while appropriately protecting your data. Analysis is run daily; if you've modified your rules in the last 24 hours those changes may not be accounted for.*

Can someone tell me how i can get out from this, and i also want to upload this app to the playstore in future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Review the section named "rules" in your firebase console (firestore section).

If you only read data from firestore you can change your rules by this. It makes firestore readonly.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can limit write permissions to authenticated users:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And setting different rules as `match` argument:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /one_collection_name/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /other_collection_name/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

There are multiple possibilities, as described in  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started.

Comment: i am aware of these basic rules, but my senior told me that if i only read data from firestore then it will decline the client access even if i update the rule for read only (i.e allow read if true), he also mentioned that if i want my firestore to work everytime then i  also have to perform create and update operation, else if i only read from database then Firebase will assume my project as inactive project and may close the client access. is this true??

Comment: Sorry @AmanSharma. I don't know about that, but I've never had a Firestore project on readonly indefinitely